# Run tag-dependent Python script on Sphinx build

Tags: python-sphinx

I need to run a simple Python script to copy a set of files from one directory to another during the build-phase of my Sphinx documentation.

**Copying function:**

location: `source/_plugins/copy_firmware_files.py`

```
import json, os, sys
from pathlib import Path
import shutil


def copy_firmware_files(device):
   # copy firmware files
```

I'm currently importing this module into my `conf.py` as the Configuration File contains the device name, which would make it a simple way to execute the code. I'm currently doing this as below:

**Configuration File (`conf.py`)**

location: `source/conf.py`

```
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath("_plugins"))
from copy_firmware_files import *

# initialize files depending on build
copy_firmware_files(device_name)
```

The above works as intended, i.e. the relevant files are copied to their respective folders before the build. However, I'm unsure if it's the "proper" way to do so. Is there a more correct way of achieving the same result?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways, but it sounds like two are most appropriate. They are static files and could be treated as such by Sphinx.

1. [`html_extra_path`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_extra_path) is one option.
2. If you want to present links to download the files, you can use the [`download` directive](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#role-download).

   ```
   See :download:`this example script <../example.py>`.
   ```

Comment: Thanks, maybe my question was unclear - what I'm looking for guidance on is how to specifically execute my custom python functions during the build process in order to move the files I need to the right directory. I.e. in which way I should ideally run the python code.

Comment: You could develop an [extension for Sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/extdev/index.html).